# underscore _,template not recognize variables on template

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I´m using underscore to load a html template with by require.js with text.js, like code bellow:

```
      template: _.template(listItemTemplate)    

      , render: function () {
            $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON));
            return this;
        }
```

***tvListItemTemplate.html***

```
<h4><%= _id%></h4>
```

If i do console.log(this.model.toJSON()) it prints the following:

[image]

But the console give me this error:

[image]

I don´t understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for that but it was a own stupid error in:

$(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON**()**));

Answer (score 1):

Check with:

```
  $(this.el).html(_.template(listItemTemplate, this.model));
```

or

```
  template: function(x) {
      _.template(listItemTemplate, x);
  },
  render: function () {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model));
        return this;
  }
```