# underscore _.template not recognizing variable

Tags: javascript, templates, coffeescript, underscore.js

[I read the last thread on this and couldn't find any syntax errors.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993238/underscore-template-not-recognize-variables-on-template) I am trying to use the _.template method in the underscore method but it is not recognize the object I am passing in. I am using coffeescript, maybe that is messing it up?

```
template = _.template("<h1>Temperature: <%= temp %> </h1>", {temp: 'test'})
$('main').append(template)
```

When I execute this code I receive the error:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: temp is not defined
```

I don't understand how this could be, I am following the underscore template exactly. Why is _.template not recognizing the variable I am passing into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
template = _.template("<h1>Temperature: <%= temp %> </h1>")({temp: 'test'})
```

Comment: Damnit, just figured it out as soon as you posted lol. Thanks Alexander. This was my first post on StackOverflow, you didn't let me down!